# Misalignment in questions thread and questions on iPod Touch (global)

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, mobile-web

I noticed a misalignment this morning on my iPod Touch while going through the questions thread on Stackoverflow.com this morning, with a white box taking up a lot of room.

It was fine yesterday.

I haven't seen a post about this and thought I would show you what it (basically) looks like on my end.

These are rough sketches as I was not able to make a screen capture of what I am seeing.

It appears to be throughout the entire StackExchange Network. I am under the impresssion that there may have been some CSS modifications done within the last 12 hours.

Whether or not this is only affecting iPod Touch and not iPhones or any other mobile devices is unknown to me.

Can someone help shine some light on the subject for me please?

Here are a few images:

**Questions thread**

[image]

**Inside a question**

[image]

Comment: It is occurring on my iPod as well. I do not know if it's on any different mobiles though.

Comment: @warspyking So I'm not the only one, ok. I wasn't hallucinating after all *lol*. We'll see if we can get an answer as the day(s) progress.

Comment: http://postimg.org/gallery/331p76w5u/ Actual screenshots

Comment: Dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279245/241919 on Meta.SE

Comment: I linked to the iPod pictures in the comment of the original as well :D

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue. I will investigate. Can you provide info of ios & safari versions?

Comment: @Paweł You're welcome. This is what I managed to pull from it Version 6.1.6 Safari/8536.25 - Is that sufficient?

Comment: Double check this. My issue on Meta was resolved. This dupe should be too.

Comment: @cde ahhhh sweet! Yeah, looks good on my end too. Thanks for the update, *cheers*

Comment: @Paweł As per cda's comment ^ it looks good on my end also, thank you and it looks great. My question can be marked as a duplicate to cda's http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279245/mobile-web-update-hurts-the-eyes if you wish, *cheers*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mobile web update hurts the eyes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279245/mobile-web-update-hurts-the-eyes)

Comment: I don't think you can close a question as a dupe across different stacks. Pawel has marked it as complete, and I put in a small answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Senior Product Designer [Pawel](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1147887/pawe%c5%82) marked this design issue as complete. Multiple users can see the fix as of 5/13/16. Resolved.

As per the Meta.SE discussion [Mobile web update hurts the eyes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279245/mobile-web-update-hurts-the-eyes) covering this issue on both Android and iOS.